# Threejs renderer screen is stuck while screenlock on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have created a renderer screen using `threejs` `WEBGL` renderer,if screen is locked in mobile devices I am unable to rotate,zoom and pan the loaded model. Can any one suggest any solution for this

Comment: Are touch events fired on locked screen? What behavior you expect?

Comment: @mlkn After unlocking the screen, the renderer canvas is stuck. Not able to rotate inside the canvas

Comment: hm, I couldn't reproduce it on multiple devices. What device are you using and does it still fail on [three example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=orbi#misc_controls_orbit)?

Comment: @mlkn I am using ipad

Comment: The browser may lost it's opengl contexts when put to background. Check if your canvas lose it's context https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/HandlingContextLost. AFAIK Three js don't handle context loss out of the box, so you have to handle it on yourself.

Comment: I am not losing model  from the rendered screen I am only facing issues in control for the model